# What is the error in this function?

Tags: python

I have to create a function that returns the sum of all the population belonging to this excel file, but I always obtain 0. What's wrong? 
Here's the file [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/eUVoB.png
This is the code:

```
def howmanyPeople(filename):

    """ howmanyPeople(String) -> int

    Receives the filename as an input and returns a number
    with the total population (sum of all countries) """

    openFile = open(filename, 'r')
    result = 0
    openFile.readline() #Skips the first line (header)
    for line in openFile:
        populationArray = line.split(",") #Returns a list with the line divided where there is a comma
        if (len(populationArray) == 3): #Checks if the name is double
            result += int(populationArray[1])
        else:
            result += int(populationArray[2])
    return result
    openFile.close()
```

Comment: Can you indent this properly?

Comment: Could you provide us your data file?

Comment: The code looks fine so the problem is probably in the underpinning assumptions. Add a print to show what's being added in each iteration for a start.

Comment: Welcome to StackExchange! Your code is not complete. Please show how this function is called, with example data, expected output, actual output, and any tracebacks. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Also, nothing in your code relates to an Excel file, just to a text file.

Comment: By the by, the `return` causes the `close` to never happen. You want to switch their order, or refactor to use `with open() ...` to avoid the need to close the input file.

Comment: Depends on the meaning of "Excel file". Excel can save as CSV which is just text, but of course, a regular `.xlsx` file would not work as input here.

Comment: @tripleee: True, but a CSV file is not usually called an Excel file, since many other programs also work with such files. I wanted the OP to explain the CSV file, of course.

Comment: One point subtracted for useless title. Use [edit] button to retrieve.

Comment: @tripleee: there is also the chilling possibility that OP's "Here's the file" is to be taken literally – i.e., that PNG file. (It isn't. I get an `IndexError` when trying.)

Comment: I already downvoted (for general lack of clarity and absence of indication of any debugging effort) but would do so again for posting a screen shot of your data. [Please don't post pictures of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/874188) and more specifically, please clarify what *exactly* one line of input looks like. If indeed your program is processing text, two or three lines of the input file would probably make this question perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

You mention an excel file, but your code seems to expect a text file (maybe this is the problem?) of the following format:

```
country name 1, population 1, phone number 1
country name 2, population 2, phone number 2
...
country name N, population N, phone number N
```

and then indeed it sums populations, using the the condition in the "if" statement. I, btw, don't understand the motivation for the statement following "else".

Comment: The comment vaguely suggests that there are formatting or consistency errors in the input file such that the population information is shifted one cell to the right. Maybe the CSV data contains commas in some coutry names ("Congo, Republic of"?), and this code is too simple to handle this complication -- though of course the real solution would be to use a proper CSV parser, which would know to not split on commas inside double quotes.